# how can i resize imageButton?

Tags: android, resize, imagebutton

I want to resize my `ImageButton` using mouse on graphic layout or using code by 
`android:layout_width` , `android:layout_height`. But whenever I do this, the `ImageButton` isn't resized, in fact and it's not smaller but it is cut at the edges.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First try to use **android:background** instead of **android:src** for setting the image on the button.In most cases,it helps.If not,then see these..

- [ImageButton in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318629/imagebutton-in-android)
- [Resize ImageButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128949/resize-imagebutton)

Answer (score 37):

try setting `android:background` instead of `android:src` for setting the image on the button. That might help in your case, since it will stretch the image to your button's size. Also, you will have to specify fixed dimensions for the buttons (use `dip` instead of `px`). Example:

```
<ImageButton
     android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_more"
     android:layout_width="50dip"
     android:layout_height="50dip" />
```

Comment: for those doing it programatically, use setbackgrounddrawable or setbackground instead of setimageresource

Comment: I am having problem with changing icon color now: `android:tint="#D50000"` not working while `android:backgroundTint="#D50000"`  isn't available below v21

Answer (score 6):

From steven-byle's solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15117536/1741997), he says:

"...Use an android:scaleType="fitCenter" to have Android scale the images, and android:adjustViewBounds="true" to have them adjust their bounds due to scaling..."

It works for me

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because sometimes you need the background tag to design the border only, and src for inside image. In this case this method works best.

Answer (score 4):

```
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_star_border"
    />
or
       <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use NinePatchDrawable... A resizeable bitmap, with stretchable areas that you define.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/NinePatchDrawable.html

Comment: I don't understand. I'm trying to use a system image for my button.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the problem with size of your image..Try to use resized image then use it in your image button.Then you can set the width and height of the button .

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this problem is to create a bitmap from the drawing resource in question then transform it into a scaled bitmap with the desired size. I also set the background to transparent to only show the image.

```
    int height = 300;
    int width = 500
    Bitmap bmp;
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.myresourcename);
    bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height, true);
    ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(this.getActivity());
    imageButton.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    imageButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Then add it to a layout.

Answer (score 0):

Applying [cesargastonec's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44083710/5105301) answer will fit the image in your ImageButton without much room to spare. If you are using a png, you can move the image to a bigger background **to get an even smaller image**.

For example, moving a 48x48 image in a 256x256 background to a 512x512 background will half its size in an ImageButton with android:scaleType="fitCenter".

This approach is best applied to an image you intend to only use in ImageButtons as it may be awkwardly scaled elsewhere and have a deceptively large clickbox.