# ImageButton not rescaling

Tags: java, android

My ImageButton isn't rescaling like the code is telling it to. Infact it's not doing anything.

Code:

```
public void getScreenRes(){
    DisplayMetrics display = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = display.widthPixels;
    int height = display.heightPixels;
    int buttonheight = display.heightPixels / 8;
    double buttonwidth = buttonheight * 2.66666667;
    int buttonwidthint = (int) Math.round(buttonwidth);
    ImageButton firsttimeFB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.firsttime_fb);
    firsttimeFB.setMaxWidth(buttonwidthint);
    firsttimeFB.setMaxHeight(buttonheight);
}
```

XML

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/facebook"
    android:id="@+id/firsttime_fb"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that in xml you're defining width and height as "wrap_content"

Look at this answer:
[Resize ImageButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128949/resize-imagebutton)

Comment: I changed it but it's still not doing anything it's staying as the XML is set. I want it to resize dynamically to the size I give it

Answer (score 0):

Replace your last three lines of code to:

```
ImageButton firsttimeFB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.firsttime_fb);
firsttimeFB.getLayoutParams().width=buttonwidthint;
firsttimeFB.getLayoutParams().height=buttonheight;
```

You should set width instead of max width and same for height.

Comment: Method Call Expected on the second and third lines

Comment: Nevermind, I formatted width and height with parenthesis' after it, but it's still not scaling correctly.

Comment: It's not scaled correctly though, still way off. Image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19296530/Valour/error1.png

Comment: check what pixels is going in buttonheight.

Comment: what do you mean? it should be the displays total pixels in height divided by 8.